# Xorg.conf leaves me with no visible output

Tags: xorg, nvidia

I have yet another laptop which is a casualty of the proprietary Nvidia driver.  I would like to do CUDA development on the laptop (Dell Precision 5510 with Quadro M1000M and 4k display), so I want the proprietary driver.

I have tried for several hours now, even reading through [this](http://us.download.nvidia.com/solaris/1.0-9755/README/chapter-02.html), and I just don't know how to configure xorg when it won't autoconfigure.  I used `nvidia-xconfig` to set my `xorg.conf` initially, then I had to add a `BusID` setting to the `Device` section in order to find the card.  Now, `startx` runs without errors (and I can verify things are actually working), but it's like it's only showing on a ghost screen.  I can run `DISPLAY=:0 xrandr` remotely and I get a 8x8 virtual screen with no outputs:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 8 x 8, maximum 16384 x 16384
```

I get the following chunk of Nvidia-related output in my xorg log file, with a couple of suspicious NULL values:

```
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jul 16 22:35:15 2016
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
(**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
(**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
(**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
(**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
(**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"

...

(**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
(==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
(==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
(==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
(**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
(II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU Quadro M1000M (GM107GL-A) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
(--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes
(--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 82.07.82.00.23
(II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
(II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
(II) NVIDIA(0):     "NULL"
(II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 640 x 480
(WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
(==) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (75, 75); computed from built-in default
(--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
(II) NVIDIA: Using 12288.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
(II) NVIDIA:     access.
(WW) NVIDIA(0): ACPI: AC power state information is not available under
(WW) NVIDIA(0):     /sys/class/power_supply/ , nor under
(WW) NVIDIA(0):     /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/
(II) NVIDIA(0): Built-in logo is bigger than the screen.
(II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
(==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
(==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
(==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
(**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
```

Here is my current `xorg.conf`:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 367.35  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-01)  Mon Jul 11 23:51:45 PDT 2016


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "LaptopBuiltin"
    ModelName      "eDP1"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    #BusId          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying that you previously had no `xorg.conf`, and that you created it with that content, then I would start simpler. You don't need all that.

All you should need to utilize the nvidia driver is:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
EndSection
```

You might also need the following for OpenGL:

```
Section "Files"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib64/opengl/nvidia"
EndSection
```

*(exact value depends on your system paths)*

If that still doesn't work, please post the entire xorg log.

Comment: Thanks for helping!  I tried that xorg file, and it was the same effect as before I put in the BusID: it says it doesn't find any nvidia devices, and then my xserver works but I don't have any GLX support (though in the log I can see it tried to do GLX).  I also didn't find any `opengl` folder except in something related to LibreOffice.  On the other hand, if I specify the BusID, I get the same situation as mentioned above, with GLX working but no visible X server.  Would you like the with- or without-BusID xorg log file? Or both?